# Printing out one line of a file in a Ruby script

Tags: ruby

I am going through "Learn Ruby the Hard Way" and I came across the method `print_a_line` in exercise 20.

```
input_file = ARGV.first
current_file = open(input_file)

def print_a_line(line_count, f)
  puts "#{line_count}, #{f.gets.chomp}"
end

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

This method is about to take the current line count and output to the terminal only the contents of the file from that line. I don't understand how the method knows to print the line of the file that is associated with `current_line`. When I look at this I would think `#{f.gets.chomp)` would return the entire contents of they file. How does the method know to look at the `current_line` and print out the associated line of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-gets) method being called in `print_a_line` reads a single line from the file (not the entire contents). The `File` object referenced by `current_file` keeps track of the current position within the file, so each time `gets` is called, the next line is returned.

Nothing is looking at `current_line` to determine which line to read.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!